# Error when importing react-native-router-flux

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I am trying to make use of a package called react-native-router-flux;

But each time I import it:

```
import { Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
```

I got this weird error:

```
 TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction')
```

And I have both Packages Installed:

```
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
 "react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
```

So what´s the source of it?

Answer (score 0):

pod install on ios folder works for me

```
cd ios
pod install
```

source : https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/676